# azure analysis service: how to start and pause service with on premise powershell

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I need your help.

I have an azure analysis service that I want to start and pause at different times of the day.
I want to use Powershell to execute a script to do this task.
Do you know how I can do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi Lidou123, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help.

Comment: HI Liduo123, If it is useful for you, could you please accept it as an answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps to start and pause Azure Analysis services with on premise powershell:**

**Step1:** Import Az.AnalysisServices module
To create a server in your subscription, you use the Az.AnalysisServices module. Load the Az.AnalysisServices module into your PowerShell session.

```
   Import-Module Az.AnalysisServices
```

**Step2:** Sign in to Azure
Sign in to your Azure subscription by using the Connect-AzAccount command. Follow the on-screen directions.

```
 Connect-AzAccount
```

**Step3:** [Only run if you have multiple Azure Subscription].
The Set-AzContext cmdlet sets authentication information for cmdlets that you run in the current session. The context includes tenant, subscription, and environment information.

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

**Step4:** Gets the details of an Analysis Services server.
The Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer cmdlet gets the details of an Analysis Services server.

```
Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup03" -Name "testserver"
```

> To **start Azure Analysis services**, use **Resume-AzAnalysisServicesServer**

The Resume-AzAnalysisServicesServer cmdlet resumes an instance of Analysis Services server

```
Resume-AzAnalysisServicesServer -Name "testserver" -ResourceGroupName "testgroup"
```

> To **stop Azure Analysis services**, use **Suspend-AzAnalysisServicesServer**

The Suspend-AzAnalysisServicesServer cmdlet suspends an instance of Analysis Services server

```
Suspend-AzAnalysisServicesServer -Name "testserver" -ResourceGroupName "testgroup"
```

**Reference:** [Azure Analysis services – Azure PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.analysisservices/?view=azps-4.4.0#analysis_services)

Now using Azure Automation, you can [schedule start & stop of Azure Analysis Services](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/12/schedule-start-stop-of-azure-analysis.html) as per required time in a day.